# building CRF-RNN tensorflow implementation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, recurrent-neural-network, crf

While trying to implement CRF as RNN in tensorflow, given the instructions here: https://github.com/liangy1969/CRF-RNN_Tensorflow , I encountered an error below.

```
onur@onur-GE62VR-6RF:~/tf_kodlar/CRF-RNN_Tensorflow-master/src$ python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace

running build_ext

building '_permutohedral' extension

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict
-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security
-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c 
permutohedral_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/permutohedral_wrap.o

cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for
C/ObjC but not for C++
permutohedral_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject*
_wrap_PermutohedralLattice_get_enclosing_simplices(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
permutohedral_wrap.cxx:4056:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘long long 
unsigned int*’ to ‘size_t* {aka long unsigned int*}’ [-fpermissive]

arg2 = (unsigned long long*) array_data(array2);
     ^
permutohedral_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject*
_wrap_PermutohedralLattice_get_blur(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
permutohedral_wrap.cxx:4166:10: error: invalid conversion from ‘long long 
unsigned int*’ to ‘size_t* {aka long unsigned int*}’ [-fpermissive]
arg2 = (unsigned long long*) array_data(array2);
     ^
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

In  the link I gave above, liangy1969 provides permutohedral.py and _permutohedral...pyd already, but directly trying to use them gave the issue here: https://github.com/liangy1969/CRF-RNN_Tensorflow/issues/1 it was concluded that the reason might be that the files were compiled in win64 and each need to build on your own. But while building I got the error above.

One more addition, in setup.py the guy gives the statement: include_dirs=['$PYTHON_PATH/Lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include']

I couldn't find my python_path, or any numpy/core/include under site-packages but I found numpy/core/include under /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages so I changed the code from site-packages to dist-packages. I don't know if that is a right move or not, unfortunately I am not an expert on python or linux environment yet. There might occur maybe a very silly mistake of mine, sorry in case.

I am using python3 (3.5) and tensorflow r1.3 (if needed) and ubuntu 16.04. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: I modified setup.py with import numpy as np and np.get_include() instead of whole pathname. No use, same error remains. Anybody help?

Comment: the problem is solved with the comment of liangy1969 as below:
"Probably the 'permutohedral_wrap.cxx' you generated using swig is not correct. Try using the following one
permutohedral_wrap.txt
Change the suffix to cxx"
check:https://github.com/liangy1969/CRF-RNN_Tensorflow/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I removed one of the 'long' type specifiers. so instead of `(unsigned long long*)` it is just `(unsigned long*)`

As for the numpy path. Here is my setup.py:

```
permuto_module = Extension('_permutohedral', sources = ['permutohedral_wrap.cxx', 'permutohedral.cpp'], include_dirs=['/home/hallab/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include'])
```

my numpy headers are in .local, took me a while to find ahah.